# Session attribute is null at first load

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following `servlet`:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Placeholder",urlPatterns = {"/foo"})
public class Placeholder extends HttpServlet {
    public static int numbers=5;
    HttpSession session;
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest _req, HttpServletResponse _res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        /* Refresh session attributes */
        session = _req.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("wee","ok");
        }
}
```

With the following `JSP`:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*, java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="main.java.Placeholder.*" %>
<html>
<body>
<b><% out.println("wee, printing from java");%></b>
<% out.println("<br/>Your IP address is " + request.getRemoteAddr());
String value = (String) session.getAttribute("wee");
out.println(value);%>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm surely missing the point somewhere as attribute `wee` is resolved as `null`, first time I load the page. If I go to `/foo` I get empty an page, and after I get back and reload the root page of `servlet`, `wee` actually gets its value.

My goal here is to simply print variables from the `servlet` into the view, no routing needed. Not sure that `urlPatterns` are needed here, but it does not work for now without this little hack.

**UPD.** Ok, so I've figured out that whatever route I put in, I need to add some characters in browser, get back and reload the page.
So, the root is `0.0.0.0:8080/webapp`

I need to access,say `0.0.0.0:8080/webapp/qwerty` , get back to `/webapp` and refresh the page.

How do I get session instantiated by just going to /webapp?
Why don't I have 404 or 500 on accessing some random unexisting route `/webapp/randomstuff`?

Comment: check is `session.getAttribute("wee")` null .if not print

Comment: Your servlet must be executed first to set session till than you won't get session value in JSP.

Comment: But if I leave it without urlpatterns, it's not ever instantiated...

Comment: You have to pass request from servlet to JSP than and than session gets instantiated and you get session value in JSP till than it will be null.

Comment: @NaMaN - how do I do it?

Comment: Also, session must NOT be an instance variable. Make it a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First configure servlet as welcome file in `web.xml`. If `web.xml` not present than create it manually inside WEB-INF folder and put below content inside it.

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>foo</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

than in your servlet dispatch request to your jsp lets say your jsp name is `index.jsp` than your servlet code would be look like:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Placeholder",urlPatterns = {"/foo"})
public class Placeholder extends HttpServlet {
    public static int numbers=5;
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest _req, HttpServletResponse _res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = _req.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("wee","ok");
        _res.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
}
```

Now run your servlet you will see output.
Hope this solve your problem!!!

Comment: Cool, works for me. Any reason for that redirect being necessary. I mean, without it, manual opening of url to get session is kind of un-natural to me...