# how to load values in dropdown using jstl

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, jstl

I am searching a way to populate a dropdown using jstl. I need to do this when page is loading. I tried some code. But it is not working.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  
 <select>
         <c:forEach items="${requestScope.personList}"  var="person">
         <option value="${person.getId()}">${person.getName()}
         </option>
         </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

And this is my controller servlet code.

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
        CasualLeaveService service1 = new CasualLeaveServiceImpl();
        List<Person> personList = service1.searchName();
        request.setAttribute("personList", personList);
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/casual");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my server class code.

```
public List<Person> searchName() {
    List<Person> list = null;
    try (DaoSession session = DaoSessionFactory.createSession()) {
        EmployeeDao emp = session.getEmployeeDao();
        list = emp.findAllPersons();
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("My list is :"+list);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in list");
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

My Person class

```
    public class Person {

private int id;
private String employeeNo;
private String name;

@ValidNo(message = "Must be a number between 1 to 999")
private Integer epfNo;

public Person() {
}

/**
 *
 * @param id
 * @param employeeNo
 * @param name initials + surname
 * @param epfNo
 */
public Person(int id, String employeeNo, String name, Integer epfNo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.employeeNo = employeeNo;
    this.name = name;
    this.epfNo = epfNo;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmployeeNo() {
    return employeeNo;
}

public void setEmployeeNo(String employeeNo) {
    this.employeeNo = employeeNo;
}

/**
 *
 * @return initials + surname
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name initials + surname
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getEpfNo() {
    return epfNo;
}

public void setEpfNo(Integer epfNo) {
    this.epfNo = epfNo;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 67 * hash + this.id;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Person other = (Person) obj;
    return this.id == other.id;
}
```

}

My Web.xml is mapped like this.

```
<servlet>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/views/leave/CasualLeave.jsp</jsp-file>
    <servlet-name>casualLeave</servlet-name>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>casualLeave</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/casual</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I can assure that service class is working perfectly fine. Because I just called this service class method directly to jsp and output is coming perfectly. The problem is using jstl this methods are not working. 

Can you tell me what is the error. Because I don't like to use scriptlet tags within jsp html code. I heard it is bad practice. 

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any error, or just no `<option>` is rendered? Anyway, I'd start with using `<option value="${person.id}">${person.name}</option>` (instead of `getId()` and `getName()`).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Still no output. I have a doubt is jstl will not work in page loading event

Answer (score 1):

This is almost right but instead of method like `${person.getId()}` you have to  write property name like `${person.id}` because when you write `${person.id}`, it will automatically call `getId()` method of `person` bean. So try using below code :

```
 <select>
     <c:forEach items="${personList}"  var="person">
         <option value="${person.id}">${person.name}</option>
     </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

Comment: Have you added proper `<%@taglib>` part?

Comment: Oh.okay..Add your `Person` class.

Comment: No erros. Just no output

Comment: Then the problem is something else. Check your list is coming in jsp or not.

Comment: When I directly called service class from jsp list is working perfectly

Comment: And when you called service class from servlet then?

Comment: Check your servlet, try to print list in console.

Comment: I tried to check like if (personList.isEmpty()) .. but no output from if or else.

Answer (score 1):

To load list in jsp you need to pass request from servlet first than and than your jsp will get `personList` in request and as you are already dispatching request from servlet your jsp will open with values in dropdown so no need to run jsp directly.

To get idea about how to open servlet first see [Session attribute is null at first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780607/session-attribute-is-null-at-first-load/30782697#30782697)

Or let say you are calling `CasualLeave.jsp` from anchor link

```
<a href="CasualLeave.jsp">Show form</a>
```

so instead putting jsp name put servlet URL pattern

```
<a href="servletURLpattern">Show form</a>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually I mapped this jsp url in web.xml. Real path is WEB-INF/leave/CasualLeave.jsp. Mapped one is casual

Comment: Okay, does your `searchName()` method print list?

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand

Comment: In question where you have `This is my server class code.` in that you have wrote `if (!list.isEmpty())` does this if-else prints list or not?

Comment: Nothing is printing out dear. Not if or not else. Thats why I'm guessing there is no call for controller class from jsp

Comment: `no call for controller class from jsp?` how you are executing your code? your servlet needs to be executed first if you want list on jsp.

Comment: Yeah I know. Please understand this. I run jsp==>JSTL cord load==> Controller==>Service like this order

Comment: Yes you running your jsp first so there is no `personList` available in request so list would be empty. JSTL code loads but no call to servlet. How you are calling servlet?

Comment: I'm not. That is the problem. How can I call the servlet. Please tell me.

Comment: My casual is not startup page. :( Is there an option to that. Plz Plz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82270/discussion-between-naman-and-dilini-rathnayake).

Comment: I think your answer is right. But problem is foreach scope can't see that request variable. I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the missing part. 

when jsp is calling "by clicking button or clicking link" you should first got to controller and then controller will redirect the jsp. 

Thank you all for your support.